# How can I use Laravel directives to import a controller file into a blade file and avoid the '$catData is undefined' error?

Tags: php, laravel-8

This is form_add_sub_category.blade.php file

```
@extends('layout.layout_01')

{{--identity the content form the layout--}}
@section('content')

    <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header">Add Item Sub Category Details</h5>
        <div class="card-body">

            <div class="input-field p-2">
                <label>Item Category Name :</label>
                {{--load combo list--}}
                <div class="col-md-5">
                <select name="cmbCategory" id="cmbCategory" >
                    @foreach(**$catData** as $row)
                        <option value="{{$row->id}}">{{$row->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field p-2">
                <label>Item Category Code :</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" readonly name="txtCatCode" id="txtCatCode">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field p-2">
                <label>Item Sub Category Name :</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Item Sub Category Name" required name="txtSubCatName">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field p-2">
                <label>Item Sub Category Code :</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Sub Category Code" required name="txtSubCatCode">
            </div>
            </div>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" id="btnAdd">ADD</a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

This is subCategoryController Class

```
 public function index(){

        $catData = InvCategory::select('id','name')->get();
        return view('form_add_sub_category',['catData' => $catData]);

    }
```

Error is "$catData is undefined".
Please explain how to fix this error.

I want to load controller class into the blade file using Laravel directives.

Comment: You're passing `$catData` to `form_add_sub_category.blade` file and trying to access in `category.blade` that's an obvious error.

Comment: sorry, I miss the correct file name. Now I corrected it.